# Dropzone accepted files filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm trying to create a file upload for STL files. The code below works as in that in the onDrop function the console.log shows an empty array for all other file types and the files if they are of type STL. So it does what it's supposed to do.

However the line

```
{isDragReject && 'File type not accepted, sorry!'}
```

always fires, even for stl files. Which certainly would confuse the user.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import Dropzone, { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';

const FileDropzone = () => {
const maxSize = 100000000;

const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
    console.log(acceptedFiles);
}, []);

const {
    isDragActive,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragReject,
    acceptedFiles,
    rejectedFiles,
} = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: '.stl',
    minSize: 0,
    maxSize,
});

const isFileTooLarge =
    rejectedFiles &&
    rejectedFiles.length > 0 &&
    rejectedFiles[0].size > maxSize;

return (
    <div className="container text-center mt-5">
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            {!isDragActive && 'Click here or drop a file to upload!'}
            {isDragActive && !isDragReject && "Drop it like it's hot!"}
            {isDragReject && 'File type not accepted, sorry!'}
            {isFileTooLarge && (
                <div className="text-danger mt-2">File is too large.</div>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

export default FileDropzone;
```

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, please see details here: https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/888

Solution: Downgrade to previous version of DropZone.